# MySQL statement ON DUPLICATE KEY for not keys

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a game that requires the user (primarily kids) to combine a prefix and a suffix into a unique username, say, BlueBaron. Now there's only so many prefixes and suffixes, so if a user generates an existing one, a number is appended to it, say, BlueBaron2.

I have a table as follows:

```
| id | prefix_id | suffix_id | identifier_index | username | hashbrown | salt | coins | ranking | date_created | date_updated
```

The `id` is an auto-increment, unique, not-null primary key - I assume for this particular instance, I won't actually need to worry about the `id`. The `prefix_id` and `suffix_id` are not-null, but because they refer to common prefixes and suffixes, they are not unique. The rest of the rows are just not-nulls.

Ideally, I would like to check if a new user has the exact same `prefix_id` and `suffix_id` as another user, and increment the `identifier_index`.

I tried this with multiple (SELECT then INSERT) statements, but I fear the data might not be updated / unique (another user might have inserted between the time it took for you to insert, etc.).

Is this possible within a single insert statement? I've read of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` but I'm not sure that's applicable here.

**UPDATE:**

Per the comments and answers below, I've created a unique index for the three columns in question:
[image]

However, the `identifier_index` increments even when the prefix_id and suffix_id are different. And in the case of the last entry, wouldn't increment at all resulting in a duplicate entry error:

[image]

Comment: If the goal is to make this check only when a new user is created, I think you should do this in your application, and not the database. That would be simpler and more logical.

Comment: @ThomasG well, the goal it's a web game, with an API gateway and lambda backend. I went with the database approach because it's the last step in the process. Perhaps I'm not imaginative enough, but I can't see a way for the website to do that.

Comment: FIrst you should do your check like this : `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(identifier_index),0) AS max_identifier_index FROM thetable WHERE prefix_id=xxxx AND suffix_id = yyyyy`. If the max_identifier_index = 0 it means that there's no record with that prefix and suffix yet, if greater than 0 , you increment the value by 1. Then you make your INSERT query

Comment: Isn't there a danger that, between your `SELECT` statement, and the `INSERT` statement, someone else has inserted into the table, thereby making the results of the `SELECT` statement void?

Comment: Good remark. I'll provide you with a proper answer later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. I'm no developer, but from a database admins view, I'd say that you need to do it like this.

You definitely need a unique index spanning over the 3 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prefix_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `suffix_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `identifier_index` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uidx_psi` (`prefix_id`,`suffix_id`,`identifier_index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This is a must, you want to guarantee data integrity!

Your insert statement would look like this:

```
insert into a (prefix_id, suffix_id, identifier_index) 
select 'asdf', 'qwer', coalesce(max(identifier_index) + 1, 1) 
from a 
where prefix_id = 'asdf' and suffix_id = 'qwer';
```

Be aware though, that you can run into deadlock issues. This happens when another transaction is trying to insert while this query is still running. Deadlocks are no serious issue, though. Typically an application is built in a way, that it simply tries again, until the insertion is successful.

Comment: Hmmm. What's this line `UNIQUE KEY 'uidx_psi' ('prefix_id','suffix_id','identifier_index')` for?

Comment: This ensures your data integrity. A unique index makes sure that there are no duplicates (spanning over the 3 columns). You don't want the row ('asdf', 'qwer', 1) multiple times, don't you?

Comment: This is more or less the proposal I was going to make. The unique key ensure that you will never have any doubles,  in the case that you rised in the comments. It will return up an erorr instead, that you can catch to try the INSERT query again. +1

Comment: I'll give this a shot as soon as I can and post back my results. I'm not in front of a PC myself. But thanks!

Comment: @fancyPants I tested it out on MySQL workbench. I also added that `uidx_psi` in the indexes. Unfortunately, it seems the identifier index just increments a different username, and in some cases, refuses to increment at all, resulting in an error of duplicate entry. I've updated the question to include pictures. Of note though is that the table has since have more columns added to it. Could that have been the cause of the issue?

Comment: @zack_falcon You noticed that you have to specify the values you want to insert two times? One time in the select clause and one time in the where clause. It works flawlessly for me.

Comment: Aha! Missed that! Yes, it works flawlessly indeed. Thanks!