# MySQL: Coalesce doesn't work on table with unique index

Tags: mysql

Similar to a previous question I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252727/mysql-statement-on-duplicate-key-for-not-keys), I have a table storing the theme, the prefix, and the suffix of user-generated maps, with the idea that no map could ever have the same name due to an identifier index.

Here's my table (other fields removed to keep it short):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `map_theme` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `map_prefix_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `map_suffix_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `map_identifier_index` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  UNIQUE KEY `uidx_atc` (`map_theme`,`map_prefix_id`,`map_suffix_id`,`map_identifier_index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

And here's a sample insert statement, based off the insert statement in the link above:

```
INSERT INTO map_info (author_id, author_time, map_theme, map_prefix_id, map_suffix_id, map_identifier_index) SELECT 3, 0, 1, 7, 3, COALESCE(MAX(map_identifier_index) + 1, 1) from map_info where map_theme = 1;
```

In theory, if a user were to insert another map with the theme of 1, prefix of 7, and suffix of 3, the map identifier to be inserted would auto-increment to 2, as a map with the same theme, prefix and suffix combo already exist. If any of those were different, the map identifier would default to 1.

In practice, however, the map identifier increments even if the prefix-suffix combo is unique, and the only thing that seems to change it up is the theme.

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, seeing as it's just one column more in the unique key from last time.

Could it be the insert statement?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(id)+1` shouldn't be used to generate new sequence numbers for an int id column. Use auto increments instead https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html - if the car limb is a foreign key to another table, make the other column an auto inc, insert to the other table, retrieve the last_inserted_id and use that in your local column

Comment: I didn't understand your "should be"s- assuming the records in your screenshot were inserted in id order, why should row with ID 2 be mapindex 1? You've just inserted a maptheme 2 with an index of 1, you're inserting another maptheme 2, the select statement calls for index = index +1 where maptheme=2 and because there is already a index 1 (id1), maptheme "should be" 2 but you said it "should be 1" - I disagree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> INSERT INTO map_info (author_id, author_time, map_theme, map_prefix_id, map_suffix_id, map_identifier_index) SELECT 3, 0, 1, 7, 3, COALESCE(MAX(map_identifier_index) + 1, 1) from map_info **where map_theme = 1;**

And also:

> the only thing that seems to change it up is the theme.

Your query will cause an incremented index to be generated based on the map_theme column only. To base your decision off more columns, they need adding to the where clause

> with the theme of 1, prefix of 7, and suffix of 3, the map identifier to be inserted would auto-increment to 2, as a map with the same theme, prefix and suffix combo already exist

So your query would need to look for other rows that have all these columns with all these values:

```
INSERT INTO map_info (author_id, author_time, map_theme, map_prefix_id, map_suffix_id, map_identifier_index) 
SELECT 3, 0, 1, 7, 3, COALESCE(MAX(map_identifier_index) + 1, 1) from map_info 

where 
  map_theme = 1 and 
  map_prefix_id = 7 and 
  map_suffix_id = 3
```

This way the index only rolls if another record with all these attributes exists

Comment: Ah, I see. I was basing my insert statement off my older insert statement, and I forgot to use the where clause. Thank you so much.